# How to query to find times of departure and arrival on laravel 5?

Tags: laravel

I tried to search for the departure hours and bus arrival hours

My database

```
id | bus_id | city | time
1  |1       |  1   | 05:00
2  |1       |  2   | 06:00
3  |1       |  3   | 07:00
```

example user choose city origin = 1 and city destination = 2

then the results I expected are

```
bus | time departure | time arrival
1   | 05:00          | 06:00
```

my query

```
$departures = Departure::whereBetween(
    'city', [
        $request->origin, $request->destination
    ])
->get();
```

Comment: Do you have any code? Did you try anything?

Comment: my code, but i'm still confused, `$departures = Departure::whereBetween('city',[$request->origin, $request->destination])
                    ->get();`

Comment: show what you tried it will be easier to help with some code examples

Comment: its my code `$departures = Departure::whereBetween('city',[$request->origin, $request->destination])
                    ->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the time of a specific bus that arrive a specific city is only one record,
you can try this or it will return the max arrival time and max departure time.

It will merge two records together(bus_1 to A, and bus_1 to b), and choose the max time as the arrival time or departure time:

```
$departure_citys = Departure::where('city',$request->origin)
                           ->selectRaw('id, 
                                        bus_id, 
                                        city,
                                        time AS time_departure, 
                                        NULL AS time_arrival');

$arrival_citys   = Departure::where('city',$request->destination)
                           ->selectRaw('id, 
                                        bus_id, 
                                        city,
                                        NULL AS time_departure, 
                                        time AS time_arrival');

$departures = $departure_citys->unionAll($arrival_citys);

DB::table(DB::raw("({$departures->toSql()}) AS tr"))
                              ->mergeBindings($departures->getQuery())
                              ->groupBy('city')
                              ->selectRaw('bus_id,
                                          MAX(time_departure) AS time_dept,
                                          MAX(time_arrival) AS time_arvl')->get();
```